# Adding service using chef opscode

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am currently working on deploying some services using chef and I need to service after that. First command i need to run is adding the service and i am able to do that with `chkconfig --add service_name` option. I am executing this command using execute block. Is there any way we can do this instead of using execute command block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue using Chef service resource with redhat. Here is the PR on Github which is still in progress. I think eventually there will either be an additional :add action or the :enable will be re-written to do chkconfig --add. http://github.com/chef/chef/pull/1120